Get Recently Inserted Data in Talend
I am inserting data form a PostgresDB to another with Talend ETL.
I insert data in a table called file, and one of the fields is size.
After i insert the data I would like to sum the size of files from a group(a column) and send to another table.
I tried to do it by using another dbinput and tmapping with the dboutput of the data I just inserted, but it doesn't work, because this dbinput is read in the beginning(when there is no data in this table). 
If i execute it a second time, then it will work because the data is already on the table.
But I would like to do it in the same job.
Is there a way that I could make by dbinput wait for all the data to be inserted in that table and read it after?


I'm not going to mark as solved, in case someone wants to add some useful info, but for me it will work better doing different jobs
